# what file downloads method used by this WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-shortcode

Which plugin is used on this website to download files? is it PHP coding?

https://freesvgdesigns.com/life-is-short-lick-the-spoon-free-svg-files-1593/

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to say exactly what method they are using but it *looks* like a JavaScript pop-up that appears with the ad which then makes an AJAX call to download the file when the close button is clicked. Unless you already have clicked the ad before in which case it looks like an AJAX call to the download page which has download headers set.

Again, difficult to say exactly how the server is working, but this is how I would have done it and it looks similar in functionality.

I suspect that this may not be a plugin at all by the way. It's just standard HTTP processing.